# Create content controls using MS Word Add-In API while inserting text

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, add-in, office-addins

I am inserting plain text paragraphs into my Word document using the Add-In, but I would like to place content controls on certain words of this paragraph *while* inserting this paragraph. Is there any way we can do that or do the content controls work only after the text is inserted?

Comment: It's always a good idea to include an example of what you've tried to provide a starting point and give people an idea of your grasp of the topic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, as demonstrated by the following code snippet, written in Script Lab by modifying a sample provided by that tool.

The trick is to work with (at least) two ranges, one for the text the other for the content control(s), as demonstrated by the code snippet, below, and illustrated in the screen shot at the end.

**Explanation**

The starting point is a `range` corresponding to the target area (the example assumes the entire document). This is then "copied" to a new `range` object for the text to be inserted (the example assumes it should come at the end of existing content).

The new text content, up to the point where a content control is required, is inserted in a new paragraph ("on a new line") - the `\n` at the start of the string.

Then a new `range` is instantiated at the end of the text range for the content control. This is inserted, formatted and text assigned to it.

The text target `range` is then set to *after* the content control range, and additional text "appended".

**Code**

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {
    let rngDoc = context.document.body.getRange("Content");
    let rngTarget = rngDoc.getRange("End");
    rngDoc.load("text"); 

    await context.sync();

    console.log(rngDoc.text);

    rngTarget.insertText("\nStart: ", "Start");
    let rngCC = rngTarget.getRange("End");
    let cc = rngCC.insertContentControl();
    cc.appearance = Word.ContentControlAppearance.boundingBox;
    cc.insertText("In content control", "Replace");

    rngTarget = rngCC.getRange("After");
    rngTarget.insertText(" End.", "After");

    await context.sync();

    console.log("Content controls inserted: " );

  });
```

**Result**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQb5Q.png]

Comment: Thanks! Will keep that in mind. Also, how can I retrieve the values of these content controls in the entire document?

Comment: Using the `context.document.contentControls;` method, a long JSON DOM is retrieved, but I'm not sure where the actual values of these content controls are?

Comment: @ShreySachdeva On Stack Overflow the rule is: one question / Question. The site's concept is a Q&A "databank", not a typical discussion forum. Please post a new question about retrieving values, but first do consider a for or foreach loop.

Comment: Got it! I just posted the question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799749/retrieve-content-controls-values-ms-word-add-in